# Can I use IIS7 to redirect traffic from a subdomain to my mac server

Tags: regex, macos, iis-7, osx-server

I'm setting up a new mac server and am going through the process of getting everything right. I want external traffic to be able to reach it so I can use profile manager to manage employee devices. At the moment it doesn't work- pushing apps and etc just hangs

The mac is sitting in the same network as a windows 2008r2 server that all external traffic goes to. I have an A record for macserver.mynetwork.com pointing to the external IP.

On the iis server I have the following rewrite rule

```
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" />
                 <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(macserver.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://theserverip/{PATH_INFO}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />

                </rule>
```

...and this seems to work for getting to the server manager frontpage but whenever I need to access any subdirectory/link i get stuck in a redirect loop.

I'm not sure if I'm completely off the rails where wasting time, the end goal is just to have profile manager working from behind the windows server.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: As Lex says, we need to use FRT to troubleshoot why your application will in a redirect loop. Normally, there is another url rewrite rule which match the rewrited url will cause this issue.